# Relation between certain Pontryagin class and Chern class

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Let $P$ be a principal $SU(2)$ bundle over base $B$, $P'$ be the principal $SO(3)$ bundle obtained by quotient $\{1,-1\}$.

How do we show the first Pontryagin class of $P'\times \mathbb{R}^3$ equals 4 times the second Chern class of $P\times\mathbb{C}^2$ ?

Comment: We have $p_1(P')=c_2(P'\otimes \mathbb{C})=2c_2(P\otimes \mathbb{C})=2c_2(P\oplus P)=4c_2(P)+2c_1(P)c_1(P)=4c_2(P)$

Comment: @Chanler Could you explain why do we have $c_2(P'\otimes \mathbb{C})=2c_2(P\otimes\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @Chanler And why do we have $c_1(P)^2=0$? Sorry I am a beginner..

Comment: We have $c_2(P'\otimes \mathbb{C})=2c_2(P\otimes \mathbb{C})$ since they are the pullback of the same class under diffrent maps. A way to see this is to draw the diagram with $X\to BSU(2)\to BSO(3)$ and then applying the complexification map. This commutes, so we just have to note that the cohomology map induced by $BSU(2)\to BSO(3)$ acts by $2$. For $c_1(P)^2=0$, it is becuase $c_1(P)=0$. This is becuase the $U(2)$ bundle can be reduced to $SU(2)$, which is an assumption, and is infact equivalent to $c_1(P)$, since it is cohomology of map $BSU(2)\to BU(2)\to BU(1)=H(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$

Comment: @Chanler Sorry I was still not clear how the map $BSU(2)\to BSO(3)$ is induced? Does the universal $SU(2)$ bundle on $BSU(2)$ give a $SO(3)$ bundle over $BSU(2)$?

Comment: And I am still confused what does it mean by complexification map commutes? I think here we only comlexified the $\mathbb{R}^3$ bundle. Do we also complexify the $\mathbb{C}^2$ bundle also?

Comment: By cohomology acts by $2$, do you mean $BSU(2)$ is a double covering of $BSU(3)$? I am not clear about this..

Comment: What do you mean by the cohomology of a map? And why the strcucture group can be reduced to $SU(2)$ implies $c_1(P)=0$? Thanks ! I have a lot to learn.

Comment: This can be seen since $c_1(P)=c_1(\det(P))=c_1(1)=0$, since the determinant bundle of a $SU(2)$-bundle is trivial, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135046/geometric-interpretation-of-reduction-of-structure-group-to-sun

Comment: $BSU(2)\to BSO(3)$ is induced by your construction, or equivalently, by the delooping of $SU(2)\to SO(3)$. The comutation $2p_1(P)=p_1(P')$ is an excersise in looking at pullbacks in a commuting diagram, which I meant to say commutes up to multipication by $2$. It is the one created by complexifying both bundles.